# bootstrap-table x-editable plugin, can't set type to select

Tags: x-editable, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap-table with the x-editable plugin, which is working mostly except I am unable to change the type of the input on the x-editable popup. I've tried setting `data-type="select"` and `type: 'select'` but it always shows as type `text`

This fiddle shows the issue, the table should be using the select type but does not, the link outside of the table with the same options does work.

```
<table id="table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <!-- this field doesn't show select input -->
            <th data-field="name" data-editable="true" data-type="select">Name</th>
            <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
            <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
            <th data-field="description">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- works! -->
<a href="#" id="fruits" data-type="select">banana</a>
```

js -

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('#table-hover');
    $table.bootstrapTable({
        }).on('editable-init.bs.table', function(e){
            $('.editable').editable('option', {
                type: 'select',
                title: "Fruit",
                source: [
                    {value: 1, text: 'banana'},
                    {value: 2, text: 'peach'}
                ]
            });
    });
    $('#fruits').editable({
       type: 'select',
       title: "Fruit",
       source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'banana'},
        {value: 2, text: 'peach'}
       ]
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/2048/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap table does not support using data attribute to init the x-editable options at the moment, you can via JavaScript instead. See this example: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#issues/986.html